# Deletar várias colunas usando o awk

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Tenho um banco de dados com 6037 colunas e 450 linhas como a abaixo:

```
1807 1452 1598 1 6.655713  A B A B ... 0 
1808 1452 1763 1 9.362033  0 0 A B ... A 
1809 1452 1527 2 6.728534  A B A A ... B 
1810 1452 1367 2 9.4055  A B A A B ... A 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1812 1452 1258 1 6.363032  0 0 A B ... B
```

Desejo obter um novo banco de dados com apenas as primeiras 676 colunas.

De preferência, alguma forma que utilize comando awk ou sed.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Utilizar-se de um loop não seria suficiente?? `awk -F" " '{ for(i=1; i<=$qntColunas; i++) print $i  }'`

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver.

Comment: Olá @andrec, Bem vindo ao SOpt, vejo que você achou uma solução. Se a sua solução e diferente das propostas pela comunidade, você pode adicionar uma resposta mostrando como você resolveu, isso seria de grande ajuda para as pessoas da comunidade que tiverem o mesmo problema. Caso alguma solução proposta pela comunidade te ajudou você pode aceitar a resposta, ao aceitar uma resposta recompensara quem te ajudou e ajudara quem tiver o mesmo problema e ainda mantem o site saudável pois sua pergunta deixa de ser uma *pergunta não resolvida*. =D -- Vale apena você dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour]

Answer (score 1):

tente:

```
awk -v f=2 -v t=676 '{for(i=f;i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s",$i,(i==t)?"\n":OFS)}'
```

solução vista em: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/35420-give-column-range-awk.html

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um arquivo de script cols.awk:

```
{
  for (i = 1; i < 676; i++)
    printf("%s ", $i)
  printf($676 "\n")
}
```

no shell rode o comando:

```
awk -f cols.awk seu_arquivo > novo_arquivo
```

That's it.

Comment: Interessante, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro:

```
awk 'NF=676'  arquivo > novo
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite.
Consegui resolver essa questão com o script abaixo:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=676;i++) {printf (i==1?"":FS)$i}; print ""}' <file.in >file.out
```

O arquivo de entrada é o "file.in", com 6037 colunas. O arquivo de saída é o "file.out", com as primeiras 676 colunas. Para obter outros arquivos com outras quantidades de colunas iniciais é só alterar o número 676 por outras quantidades de colunas.

Obrigado.